# std_msgs types and 'normal' type

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, std-msgs, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I want to display a variable on a topic. Therefore I need to transform my variable from an volatile unsigned long to an std_msgs type (for example UInt64). This gives following error:

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std_msgs::UInt64' and 'volatile long unsigned int')
```

How can i convert this long to a std_msgs?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310412/std_msgs-types-and-%27normal%27-type/) by [gab27](https://answers.ros.org/users/38206/gab27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code probably looks like :

```
std_msgs::UInt64 int_a;
volatile long unsigned int_b;
int_a = int_b;
```

But if you look at the [message definition](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/UInt64.html) you'll see that there is a field `data`, so you have to use it to set the message value :

```
std_msgs::UInt64 int_a;
volatile long unsigned int int_b;
int_a.data = int_b;
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-11**:
beat me by 20 seconds ;-)

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-12-11**:
We really need the "someone is typing.." feature ;)

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-11**:
agreed :-D